# Cumulants for a log-normal distribution

Tags: lognormal-distribution

My dataset both has a theoretical empirical log-normal distribution and the histogram shows that a log-normal distribution fits, so I am trying to figure out whether I should use a linear or non-linear model.

I know that for a Gaussian distribution there are no cumulants beyond pairwise correlations and hence a linear model is sufficient, but is this the case for a log-normal distribution as well? Or are there non-linear dependencies, i.e., beyond correlations, for a log-normal distribution which requires a non-linear model?

Alternatively, what is the link on this between a Gaussian and log-normal distribution.

Thanks

Comment: The Gaussian distributions *do* have cumulants of all orders: they just happen to equal zero beyond order 2.  Whether or not they are zero has no bearing on "sufficiency" of a linear model (whatever you might intend by that): the concepts of cumulants and linear models are not inherently related.  It's unclear what you mean by "nonlinear dependencies," which is yet another concept unrelated to existence of cumulants.  Could you therefore clarify what you are trying to ask?